# iPhone 6 Plus Wireless connection problem

Tags: iphone, wifi

My brother bought an iPhone 6 Plus, and it has a small problem.  When it connects to a wireless network, it will disconnect, and reconnect within a couple of seconds about every hour or so.

He has made sure that the software is up-to-date, and that didn`t help.

WiFi settings are Its WPA/WPA2, AES. Other iPhones connect without a problem.

What would be causing this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: and what are the WiFi settings ?

Comment: try to reset network settings

Answer (score 1):

You can go to settings go to WiFi and see if there’s anything wrong with the passwords if there’s nothing wrong with the passwords then switch up some of the network settings and that doesn’t seem to work then switch to another network type